# mmqgis plugin not showing up in plugin dropdown menu

Tags: qgis, mac, osx, mmqgis

I have installed the plugin from the plugin dialog box, but I am unable to figure out exactly how to run the plugin.

Comment: at QGIS 2.4 it should be its own menu option along the top menu bar...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean it's not showing up in the menu bar? It's not in the Plugins menu - it has its own Dropdown menu title.

[image]